# Cyclic group of order 24

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have been asked to prove or disprove the following:

> If $G$ is a group of order $24$ such that $a\in G$ , $a^{12}\ne e$  and $a^{8}\ne e$ where $e$ is the identity of $G$, then the group is cyclic.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What is $a$ supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry, I have been edited my question.

Comment: Hint: Definition of cyclic groups and Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Hints: the order of $a$ is 24, thus $G$ is cyclic. To see the order, please refer to Levent's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Lagrange's theorem, order of $a$ is a divisor of $24$. Since $a^{12}$ and $a^{8}$ are not identity, this order does not divide $12$ or $8$. Consider the divisors of $24$ and eliminate each divisor that divides $12$ or $8$. You are left with a single divisor which must be the order of $a$. What is that number?

Comment: Thank you for answering, I am understanding that 24 it the suitable divisor. But does the group (in these certain conditions) is definitely cyclic?

Comment: $a$ is an element of order $24$. The group also has order $24$. Hence the group is generated by $a$.